# How to update a value in corona SDK?

Tags: lua, coronasdk

Why is my code not working when I check the score value? I've been trying to solve this problem for a very long time but nothing works. Why does the scoreTxt update but the if function doesn't do anything?

```
local function myTouchListener( event )
   if (event.phase == "began") then
      transition.pause()   
      score = score +1
      scoreTxt.text = score   
  end
 end


 local ball = display.newCircle(0,0,40)
       ball:addEventListener("touch",myTouchListener)




 if(score > 2)then
   ball.x = display.contentCenterX
   --NOTHING HAPPENS HERE
 end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all there is no such thing as an "if function".

Assuming that the code you provided is only executed once your if statement is also only evaluated once. As score is most likely not > 2 when this happens the if statements body is not evaluated at all. That's why nothing happens.

When your code is executed you define a function myTouchListener. Then you create a circle and add the myTouchListener function as its event listener.

Then you evaluate the if-statement.

You should move that ball.x assignment to the myTouchListener to evaluate it every time score changes.

Think about it. why should the if statement be evaluated again? Who would trigger that and why?

Comment: what would trigger the if statement again? A loop of some sort? I tried to put the if statement in the function but it didn't work out very well.

Comment: @Mr.E and what in God's name is "didn't work out very well" supposed to mean?

Comment: well after I changed and put the if statement in the eventListener, I made it so if the score is higher than 2 a function begins, where the background changes from black to white repeatedly. Now every time I press on the screen the function where the  background changes starts all over again. Is there a way to check if a function is in progress and if it is finished or not?

Comment: @Mr.E disable the event listener while the current event is being processed

Answer (score 1):

This should solve the issue:

```
local score = 0
local function myTouchListener( event )
if (event.phase == "began") then
    transition.pause()   
    score = score +1
    scoreTxt.text = score   

    if(score > 2)then
        ball.x = display.contentCenterX
    end
end
end
local ball = display.newCircle(0,0,40)
ball:addEventListener("touch",myTouchListener)
```

The issue you are having is the if statement is happening once and score is equal to 0 or null. You need to check if score > 2 AFTER each touch occurs, not just once when the program is first run.

You also can't just make score = score + 1, because score actually equals null if you didn't initialize it. so null = null + 1 doesn't make any sense.